Chainlink Functions: my function run on playground but the request fails from the contract
This is my contract deployed on Optimism Sepolia.
This is my Chainlink Functions script on playground (I removed the API Keys so that anyone can test):
const wallet = args[0];
const providerId = args[1];
const apiResponse = await Functions.makeHttpRequest({
  url: `https://cloud.kycwonder.workers.dev/api/fetch-Kyc-Data/${wallet}/${providerId}`
});
        
if (apiResponse.error) {
  throw Error('Request failed');
}

const { data } = apiResponse;
const dataToEncode = BigInt(data.parsedData);

return Functions.encodeUint256(dataToEncode);

The transaction executes, but the I'm getting this error:
Computation: Error: Request failed

USE:
Arg[0] = 0x94aBa23b9Bbfe7bb62A9eB8b1215D72b5f6F33a1
Arg1 = 1

In the requestKycData() function of your KycAggregator contract, when the account value of type address is getting typecasted to string using toHexString() of LibString library, then it's getting converted to lowercase value, therefore the API is unable to process that and returning the error.
You can test the same in the playground:

When using lowercase address value, i.e., passing Argument 1 as 0x94aba23b9bbfe7bb62a9eb8b1215d72b5f6f33a1:

Output:
Error: Request failed


When using checksummed address value, i.e., passing Argument 1 as 0x94aBa23b9Bbfe7bb62A9eB8b1215D72b5f6F33a1:

Output:
71615



So, the solution is in order to typecast address to string, you can use another function of the same LibString library i.e., toHexStringChecksummed(), it would return the checksummed value of the account in string format, like:
string[] memory args = new string[](2);
args[0] = account.toHexStringChecksummed();
args[1] = providerId.toString();


The problem is with the contract; how we typecast the args fails. Fixing the contract made it work.
